# TableView RxSwift binding cause Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints warning

Tags: swift, uitableview, rx-swift, snapkit

I use SnapKit and RxSwift in my project.
in some pages, I use RxSwift tableView binding for bind data and tableView.

```
friends.compactMap{$0}.asObservable().bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: WalletTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier,
                                                                      cellType: FriendWalletTableViewCell.self))
    { (row,item,cell) in
        
    cell.wallet = item
                                                                        
}.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

when I go to these pages (when viewDidLoad) everything works fine without any "Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint" warning, but when view dismiss or pop to last view controller, this warning shows in the console:
"Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint".

cell's constraints in cells init:

```
backView.snp.remakeConstraints { (make) in
     make.width.equalToSuperview().inset(Helper.deviceCheck().isPad ? 0 : 22)
     make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
     make.top.equalToSuperview()
     make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-22)
}

icon.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
     make.width.equalTo(53)
     make.height.equalTo(47)
     make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(10)
     make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(10)
}

currencyBadge.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
     make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(16)
     make.height.equalTo(30)
     make.width.lessThanOrEqualTo(50)
     make.right.equalToSuperview().inset(16)
}

titleLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
     make.right.equalTo(currencyBadge.snp.left).offset(-10)
     make.centerY.equalTo(currencyBadge.snp.centerY)
}

separator.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
     make.width.equalToSuperview()
     make.centerX.equalToSuperview()
     make.height.equalTo(1)
     make.top.equalTo(icon.snp.bottom).offset(10)
}

sendButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
     make.width.greaterThanOrEqualTo(85)
     make.height.equalTo(35)
     make.top.equalTo(separator.snp.bottom).offset(10)
     make.right.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
     make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-10)
}
```

honestly, it's odd for me, because if auto-layout have an issue, the warning must show in viewDidLoad() or viewWillAppear().

P.S: if I implement tableView normally (with delegate and dataSource) it works without any warning.

can you please what is my mistake?
thanks

Comment: Can you show us the constraints? Bindig should not cause breaking constraint warning.

Comment: @Dris sure, adding constraints in question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

At viewDidLoad, `viewController.view.frame == .zero`, if you call `bind(to)` datasource for tableView, will cause `layoutIfNeeds` to be called. At this time the auto layout constraint will not work correctly (due to frame = .zero).
To avoid this, you can use DispatchQueue.main.async for delaying the `bind(to:)` call will suppress the warning.

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    friends.compactMap{$0}.asObservable().bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: WalletTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier,
                                                                      cellType: FriendWalletTableViewCell.self))
    { (row,item,cell) in
        
    cell.wallet = item
                                                                        
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```